# Set the fields `null=True`, why in the ModelForm I still get required error?

Tags: python, django

I get `required` error when I request the API by me.

In my `models.py`:

```
class User(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    real_name = models.CharField(max_length=12, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField( max_length=11)
    email = models.EmailField(null=True)
    qq = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=64, null=True)   
    id_card = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=18, validators=[RegexValidator(regex='^.{18}$', message='id card length:18', code='nomatch')])
    id_card_img_front = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True)
    id_card_img_back = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True)
    nickname = models.CharField(max_length=16, null=True)
    profile = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True, default='my profile')  
    usertype = models.ForeignKey(to='UserType', default=1)   
    ctime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    uptime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

In my `views.py`, please pay attention I only send `username`, `password`, `phone` to the request:

```
class UserMF(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = models.User
        fields = '__all__'

def register(request):
    ...
    obj = UserMF(request.POST)

    if obj.is_valid():
        ...
    else:
        print (obj.errors.as_json())  # then printed the errors
        ...
```

The error message:

```
{"qq": [{"message": "This field is required.", "code": "required"}], "profile": [{"message": "This field is required.", "code": "required"}],   "id_card_img_front": [{"message": "This field is required.", "code": "required"}], "id_card": [{"message": "This field is required.", "code": "required"}], "real_name": [{"message": "This field is required.", "code": "required"}], "usertype": [{"message": "This field is required.", "code": "required"}], "id_card_img_back": [{"message": "This field is required.", "code": "required"}], "address": [{"message": "This field is required.", "code": "required"}], "nickname": [{"message": "This field is required.", "code": "required"}], "email": [{"message": "This field is required.", "code": "required"}]}
```

In my models I have set the the fields (except username, password, phone) to `null=True`, why in the ModelForm I still get required error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With both `null=True` and `blank=True` on a `CharField` you will remove this required checking, but it's better to remove the `null=True`. [Django's advice](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#null):

> Avoid using null on string-based fields such as `CharField` and `TextField`. If a string-based field has `null=True`, that means it has two possible values for “no data”: `NULL`, and the empty string.

As you seem to be using only `CharField` with `null=True` I would change all of those to `blank=True`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use "fields" option in the meta class of the model form, you can specify what all fields are required as a set like

fields = ('username', 'password', 'phone')

or you can use "exclude" option in the model form meta class to remove unwanted fields like exclude ("excluded_field1","excluded_field2") etc

you can find the description here [modelform](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/modelforms/)

Answer (score 1):

Please try adding `blank=True` to all of your optional fields.

You can find more information about the `blank` parameter here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#blank

Answer (score 0):

`null=True` only means that at the database level the field is allowed to be NULL. Forms (and models) validation are not directly impacted by this option, what you need here is the `blank=True` option.

Also and FWIW, allowing NULL for charfields/textfields is usually a very bad idea since you then have two distinct "empty" values (NULL and the empty string), so for optional char/text fields you want `blank=True, null=False, default=''` to only use the empty string as empty value (nb: there are still use case for having both NULL and the empty string but from experience most of the time only having the empty string makes life easier).

And finally, you can also restrict the fieldset used in your `ModelForm` (either by explicitly listing which fields you want with the `fields` attribute - which is the recommanded way - or by excluding some fields with the `exclude` attribute).